# devexpress dxskincontroller has no skins listed

Tags: delphi, devexpress

For some unknown reson dxskins do not show up in my dxskincontroller.
Only a 'UserSkin' shows up.

[image]

All skins seem to be listed in the install directory \Library\RS26 
but no skins show up in the dxskincontroller at a design time.

How do I fix this ?
Devexpress is 19.1.2 and Delphi 10.3 update 2.

Comment: Well, why not write to DevEx support and ask them to clarify this situation?

Comment: Each skin has to be installed as a component package. This is usually done when installing devExpress, but can be opted out of. You can rerun Setup.exe from the Setup folder

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes a little late, but for version DX10.3 all skin packages (dxSkin*.bpl) must be located in \Library\RS26\Win32\bpl.